# Version Specifying in VS 2017 .csproj file

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am running .net core app in VS 2017 .In the .csproj file I have the following

```
  <ItemGroup>
...........
    <PackageReference Include="OpenIddict" Version="$(OpenIddictVersion)" />
..........
  </ItemGroup>
```

the dots representing other packages.
What I need to know is where does that $(OpenIddictVersion) variable stays?
 And how do I know which version it is taking?
And where the variable is set?

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/blob/dev/build/dependencies.props

Answer (score 0):

This `$()` syntax represent an [MSBuild property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/property-element-msbuild).

The MSBuild property can come from different places:

- From [PropertyGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/propertygroup-element-msbuild)- In MSBuild file (the `csproj` file for example), there is a section called **PropertyGroup** that contain the properties:

  ```xml
  <PropertyGroup>  
      <OpenIddictVersion>2.0.0</OpenIddictVersion>  
  </PropertyGroup>
  ```
- From [.target](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-dot-targets-files) files- The .target files declared in `csproj` files, or imported automaticly for the build.
- From the build- The build register some MSBuild properties like `configuration=Debug|Release`, it is register them by user selection (in Visual Studio) or by specific arguments in command line.
- From command line- You can register any proprty by adding the syntax `/p:OpenIddictVersion=2.0.0` to build command.

So we're missing information about your build process to figure out where your data can come from.